# Comparing items in 2 lists

Tags: python, list, compare

I've got 2 lists in the program. One list is a list of 5 generic integers and the second list contain 5 integers inputed by user.
Now I need to compare whether each of the user numbers is on the generic numbers list.
If so add a point to the player.
I have no idea where to start with it.
I don't really want a complete answer but I couldn't find any tutorial how to that kind of comparison, so I would be grateful for anything.

```
import random



#Winning numbers
def winningNumbers():
  winning_numbers = []
  for i in range(5):
    x = random.randint(1,50)
    winning_numbers.append(x)
  print("Today's winning numbers are: " + str(winning_numbers))
  return winning_numbers

#Get player numbers
def player_numbers():
  user_input = []
  while len(user_input) < 5:
    number = input("Chose the numbers from 1-50:")
    try:
      number = int(number)
    except ValueError:
      print("That's not a number!")
      continue  
    if number in user_input:
      print("You already chosen this number!")  
    elif number not in range(1,51):
      print("The number is out of range")    
    else:
      user_input.append(number)
  print("Your chosen numbers are: " + str(user_input))
  return user_input
#Compare numbers
def compare_numbers():
  player_points = 0
  for i in winning_numbers:
    for x in user_input:
        if str(x) == str(y):
            player_points = player_points + 1
        else:
            pass
  print(player_points)  



winningNumbers()
player_numbers()
compare_numbers()
```

Comment: Can you provide us the sample of data and your code? If your code doesn't work please provide a traceback.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried to do?

Comment: Incomplete answer: `sum(1 for x in user_list if ...)`

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this from [GeeksForGeeks Comparing Python Lists](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-print-common-elements-two-lists/)

This program will print out the elements that exist in both lists.

```
# Python program to find the common elements  
# in two lists 
def common_member(a, b): 
    a_set = set(a) 
    b_set = set(b) 
    if (a_set & b_set): 
        print(a_set & b_set) 
    else: 
        print("No common elements")  


a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] # here is where you would gather the lists  
b = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9] 
common_member(a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is make a nested loop, so a loop in a loop. Do it like this:

```
for i in list1:
    for x in list2:
        if str(x) == str(i):
            #Do stuff, like add up point
        else:
            #Do stuff, like subtract points, or put in 'pass' for Python to pass the condition
```

I hoped this helped you. If you've more quetions, i'll be open for them.

EDIT: This code is working, try to understand:

```
import random
global player_points
player_points = 0

#Winning numbers
def winningNumbers():
  winning_numbers = []
  for i in range(5):
    x = random.randint(1,50)
    winning_numbers.append(x)
  print("Today's winning numbers are: " + str(winning_numbers))
  return winning_numbers

#Get player numbers
def player_numbers(winning_numbers):
  user_input = []
  while len(user_input) < 5:
    number = input("Chose the numbers from 1-50:")
    try:
      number = int(number)
    except ValueError:
      print("That's not a number!")
      continue
    if number in user_input:
      print("You already chosen this number!")
    elif number not in range(1,51):
      print("The number is out of range")
    else:
      user_input.append(number)
  print("Your chosen numbers are: " + str(user_input))
  return user_input
#Compare numbers
def compare_numbers(user_input, winning_numbers):
  global player_points
  for i in winning_numbers:
    for x in user_input:
        if str(x) == str(i):
            player_points = player_points + 1
        else:
            pass
  print(player_points)

#Loop functions
while True:
    compare_numbers(player_numbers(winningNumbers()), winningNumbers())
```

Sincerly, Chris Fowl

Comment: I have added this to my code but it returning an error 'File "python", line 34, in compare_numbers
NameError: name 'winning_numbers' is not defined' I've got function for generate random number and another function for get user numbers. Both lists are returned at the end of the functions. Comparison is made in the another function

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add your full code? This way I can help you personally.

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: And I've added code too ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
set(user_input_list) & set(generic_list)
```

to get the common values in both the list.